# switchMap gives error type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput

Tags: angular, rxjs, routes, subscription, switchmap

I have a variable  `queryCode` of type `string` that depends on the value of route params so it is set under subscribe of activated route params and then using that value if it's null or not I call several other services.

I tried to use switchMap since other pieces of codes are dependent on `queryCode` but I'm getting the error `Argument of type '() => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Params, index: number) => ObservableInput<any>'. Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<any>'.`

Can somebody help me please?

```
this.route.queryParams
      .pipe(
        takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$),
        tap(queryParams => {
          this.queryCode = this.filterService.getCodeBasedQueryParams(queryParams); // this returns a string
        }),
        switchMap(() => {
          if (this.queryCode) {
            
            this.productService.dataLoaded$.subscribe((arrows: IAuctionArrows) => {
               /// some code 
            });
            this.productService.codeClosed$
              .subscribe(() => 
                 this.productService.loadNextCode(this.queryCode));
          }
        }),
        switchMap( () => {
          this.productService.userLoaded$
            .subscribe(product => {
              this.typeOfProduct = this.product-service.getProductType(product);
              if (this.queryCode && this.typeOfProduct) {
                 //some code
              }
              this.currentId = product.id;
              this.router.navigate(['/product/' + this.currentId], { queryParamsHandling: 'preserve' });
            });
        }),
      )
      .subscribe();
```

Previously I had this, but this is not reliable since if the query code is set in async block and I do the checks without making sure that its value is set.

```
ngOnInit() {

this.route.queryParams.subscribe( params => {
    this.queryCode = 
             this.filterService.getCodeBasedQueryParams(queryParams); // this returns a string
})



if (this.queryCode) {
            
   this.productService.dataLoaded$
           .subscribe((arrows: IAuctionArrows) => {
               /// some code 
            });
            this.productService.codeClosed$
              .subscribe(() => 
                 this.productService.loadNextCode(this.queryCode));
}



this.productService.userLoaded$
            .subscribe(product => {
              this.typeOfProduct = this.product-service.getProductType(product);
              if (this.queryCode && this.typeOfProduct) {
                 //some code this.currentId set here
              }
              this.currentId = product.id;
              this.router.navigate(['/product/' + this.currentId], { queryParamsHandling: 'preserve' });
            });

}
```

Comment: to get rid of ts errors, replace both `switchMap` operators with `tap`. to implement everything correctly you should learn rxjs on easier examples to understand how it works

Comment: @Andrei how can I make it work with `switchMap`? Since it will cancel all calls when having new param.  And that is what I need

Comment: you should return observable inside of a siwtchMap callback `switchMap(( => data$)` which it will subscribe on after recieving the event

Comment: @Andrei but as you can see on that piece of code, I do have one or two calls inside `if blocks` so I can't return a  observable

Comment: @Andrei  I added the piece of code that I had before trying with `switchMap` so maybe you can understand my problem

Comment: You need to return an Observable from the project function in all your `switchMap`s

Comment: can you give me an example with my code @martin cause I don't know exactly how to handle if conditions